# How can I remove a singe URL from Firefox address bar history?

Tags: firefox

I guess the titles tells it all.

I followed [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-websites-awesome-bar-suggestions#w_clearing-a-single-item-from-the-address-bar-history) guide but highlighting and deleting the link does not really remove it.

Comment: <shift><del> removes it ...

Comment: I'm afraid, it does not. I'm on linux and firefox 64.

Comment: Works here. Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 64.0

Comment: Are you using the down arrow to select the entry?

Comment: @user3169 I type the first characters and the url appears. then I press down arrow, so that it is selected. Then I shift delete it. But it appears agian!

Comment: Works OK for me, Windows 7 / FF64. How about in FF safe mode?